# Array for OR clause production Datatype Mismatch error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have the following query

```
friends_ids = [1,2,3]

Friend.where("user_id = ? or friend_id = ?", friends_ids, friends_ids)
```

However, when I run it I get

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of OR must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 1: ...CT "friends".* FROM "friends"  WHERE (user_id = 2,3 or frien...
```

It's clear the OR clause does not like arrays, so how would I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `in`, not `=`:

```
friends_ids = [1,2,3]

Friend.where("user_id in (?) or friend_id in (?)", friends_ids, friends_ids)
```